# reactjs mobile responsiveness unusual problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsiveness

I have built an web application in react.js and made it responsive using conditional rendering and media query but when i run it on browser with mobile view it sometime gives non responsive layout and sometimes gives perfect layout so i cant figure out whether there is problem with the code or is it just a glitch so im seeking the community help.

The reactjs application in mobile view sometimes gives perfect layout and sometimes doesn't so how to solve this issue so i'm trying to figure out how to solve.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately it is impossible to answer to your question without looking the code and, even with the code available, your problem seems to be so generic that is unlikely to meet the required standard to be accepted. Please try to narrow down the issue (is the behaviour really random or it can be reproduced with a set of actions?) and, once you identified a couple of points in your code which are likely candidates for the problem, share the relevant code.